# Is it possible to scope in VueJS templates so you don't have to repeat object names when referencing properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope

I'm porting some code from KnockoutJS to VueJS for an employer and in Knockout they have a `with` directive that allows object properties to be referenced without repeating the object name.

How do I do this in VueJS?  I tried looking into slot scope and template scope and even tried creating my own custom directive that modified the `data` property on the referenced VNode, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Current Code:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <div>{{item.phone}}</div>
  <div>{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Pseudo-code:

```
<div v-for="item in items" v-with="item">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  <div>{{phone}}</div>
  <div>{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

This is purely for readability purposes that I'm asking this as I have already completed the task using the repeated object identifiers when referencing its properties, but I wanted to ask in case there was something that I was missing.

Someone on the VueJS chat rooms suggested using Vuex store, but their sample didn't seem to address my concern of repetitive naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always destructure your object in the `v-for` loop, like:

`<div v-for="{name, phone} in items">`

An example would be:

```js
new Vue({
    data: {
        items: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                phone: '123-456-7890',
                otherVal: 'hello'
            },
            {
                name: 'Joe',
                phone: '234-567-8901',
                otherVal: 'goodbye'
            }
        ]
    }
}).$mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">  
  <div v-for="{name, phone} in items">
    {{ name }} {{ phone }}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going after. I realize that is just standard JavaScript syntax and nothing special related to VueJS, but I appreciate the time and sharing the "destructure" syntax with me. This is much more convenient and cleaner than repeating the object all the time.